# TreeView Style FullRowSelect and stay selected when focus lost

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, focus, fullrowselect

At a TreeView, I have the following Resources to keep the item selected when Focus is lost.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <!--  SelectedItem with focus  -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                             Opacity=".8"
                                             Color="DodgerBlue" />
                            <!--  SelectedItem without focus  -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                                             Opacity=".3"
                                             Color="DodgerBlue" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.Resources>
```

But I also have a template in a resource dictionary that I use to get a FullRowSelect style. It is from LeeCampbells Article here: [Horizontal stretch on TreeViewItems](http://leecampbell.blogspot.de/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html)

```
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--
                                    Note that the following do not work, but I believe the top 2 should?!
                                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Property=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding Path=IsExpanded}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                -->
                                <ToggleButton Name="Expander"
                                              ClickMode="Press"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable" Value="false" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Border Width="16"
                                                                Height="16"
                                                                Background="#00FFFFFF"
                                                                Padding="5,5,5,5">
                                                            <Path Name="ExpandPath"
                                                                  Fill="#00FFFFFF"
                                                                  Stroke="#FF989898">
                                                                <Path.Data>
                                                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                                </Path.Data>
                                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                            </Path>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF1BBBFA" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="UIElement.RenderTransform">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#FF595959" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF262626" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                Grid.Column="1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>




    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

</TreeView>
```

At the moment I do not seem to be able to combine those two. Perhaps it's already too late here.

Where should I put the style in the template to have FullRowSelect and keep the selection when focus is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<Style>` tags around the two color brush definitions... in other words, make the color brushes direct `Resources` of the `TreeView` rather than wrapped inside of a `Style`.